# Storing long passages of text, Android

Tags: android, textview

I am building an app,where once clicked, an item in an ExpandableListView should display a scrollable text to be read, providing certain information. What is the best approach in this situation? Is it Okey to build the activity, using TextView and inserting texts in them? The Strings are better to be stored in a database and to be dynamically loaded, or there is another way? Than you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be ok to use a textView to display data. But always make to sure to load the text in a separate thread and feed it into the textview using a handler.

```
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
tv.setHInt("Loading");

//creating hanlder
final Handler hanlder=new Hanlder(){
   @Overrride
   public void handleMessage(Message msg){
       String text=msg.getData().getString("loadedText");
       tv.setText(text);
   }
};

//new thread to load data
new Thread(new Runnable{
    @Overrride
    public void run(){
        //load content from database
        // prepare a Message object with a Bundle containing the loaded text
        Message msg=new Message();
        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("loadedText",loadedTextFromDb);
        msg.setData(bundle);

        //notify the hanlder
        handler.dispatchMessage(msg);
    }
}).start();
```

It's not good practice to use handlers like this. Stick to static handlers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Malith! I'll take advance in your advice.